# Add Checkbox to Table Cell with a Specific Class Only

Tags: jquery, html

I have a standard html table which is enhanced with a grouping plugin. When you click on the "grouping" level, the table expands to reveal any number of table rows from within that group. What I'm trying to do is add a checkbox to the last table cell in the grouping level when the group is expanded. When I try to do this, all grouping levels receive a checkbox, not just the one that I clicked.

**HTML Code (sanitized and simplified)**

```
<!--Grouping Row 1 Expanded-->
<tr id="group-id-example_XXX">
<td colspan="11" class="expanded-group" data-group-level="0">
<div class="checkboxinput"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value=""></div>
</td>
</tr>
<!--Grouping Row 1 Expanded-->

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<!--Grouping Row 2 Collapsed-->
<tr id="group-id-example_XXX">
<td colspan="11" class="collapsed-group" data-group-level="0">
<div class="checkboxinput"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value=""></div>
</td>
</tr>
<!--Grouping Row 2 Collapsed-->

</tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery Function**

```
 $('tr[id^="group-id-example"]').on('click', function() {
$(this).find('td').addClass('test');
    if ($('#example tr td').hasClass('test')) {
        $('.checkboxinput').show();
    } else {
        $('.checkboxinput').hide();
    }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are showing/hiding all the checkboxes when you use `$('.checkboxinput')`. Also `.hasClass()` will return true if any of the element in the passed element set has the given class, since you are adding the class to some tds in the previous line your if condition will always return true.

```
var $checks = $('.checkboxinput');
$('tr[id^="group-id-example"]').on('click', function () {
    var $cchecks = $(this).nextUntil('tr[id^="group-id-example"]').find('.checkboxinput').toggle();
    $checks.not($checks).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Arun. This doesn't add any checkboxes on the expanded-group level, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arun for getting me on the right track. What worked for me is changing .nextuntil() to .closest(). I have to admit, though, that I don't completely understand why .nextUntil() doesn't work here.

```
var $checks = $('.checkboxinput');
$('tr[id^="group-id-example"]').on('click', function () {
var $cchecks = $(this).closest('tr[id^="group-id-example"]').find('.checkboxinput').toggle();
$checks.not($checks).hide();
});
```